# Why does my delayed_job fail without RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, delayed-job

I have a `delayed_job` installed, and I start the daemon to run the jobs with this Ruby script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemon_spawn'
$: << '.'

RAILS_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..'))

class DelayedJobWorker < DaemonSpawn::Base
  def start(args)
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= args.first || 'development'
    Dir.chdir RAILS_ROOT
    require File.join('config', 'environment')

    Delayed::Worker.new.start
  end

  def stop
    system("kill `cat #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid`")
  end
end

DelayedJobWorker.spawn!(:log_file => File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "log", "delayed_job.log"),
                    :pid_file => File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'tmp', 'pids', 'delayed_job.pid'),
                    :sync_log => true,
                    :working_dir => RAILS_ROOT)
```

If I run the command with `rvmsudo` it works perfectly.

If I simply use the Ruby command without RVM it fails and this is the output. I have no idea why this happens. Could you give me some clue?

```
user@mysystem:~/redeal.it/application$ ruby script/delayed_job start production
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/daemon-spawn-0.4.2/lib/daemon_spawn.rb:16:in `kill': Operation not permitted (Errno::EPERM)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/daemon-spawn-0.4.2/lib/daemon_spawn.rb:16:in `alive?'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/daemon-spawn-0.4.2/lib/daemon_spawn.rb:125:in `alive?'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/daemon-spawn-0.4.2/lib/daemon_spawn.rb:176:in `block in start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/daemon-spawn-0.4.2/lib/daemon_spawn.rb:176:in `select'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/daemon-spawn-0.4.2/lib/daemon_spawn.rb:176:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/daemon-spawn-0.4.2/lib/daemon_spawn.rb:165:in `spawn!'
from script/delayed_job:37:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a permission issue.

Putting it simply: You have a delayed job running under another user (proprably `root` due to using `rvmsudo`), and daemon spawn is trying to kill it. You will get an `Operation not permitted`.

Try killing delayed_job first with rvmsudo, make sure it is not running (try `ps aux`) and then try to start without `rvmsudo`.

It should work.

Answer (score 4):

First, take a look at shared/pids/delayed_job.pid and see if process is running. In my case it  looked like it was shut down unclean and pid file was left in place. Deploy script was trying to kill non-existing process and was giving that permission error.

I have deleted delayed_job.pid and deploy succeeded.