# delayed_job dies with out error -- leaving job in locked state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, delayed-job

After DJ dies the log files indicate nothing.

running: `./script/delayed_job status`

gives: `pid-file for killed process 1143 found (/appPath/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid), deleting.`
`delayed_job: no instances running`

The strange thing is if I use: `./script/delayed_job run` It will run perfectly in the foreground! And never dies.

Tried many versions of `delayed_job` and `mongoid` with same results.

Any one know how to debug?

Using:

`rails (3.2.7)`

`delayed_job_mongoid (2.0.0)`

`mongoid (3.0.3)`

`delayed_job (3.0.3)`

Comment: DJ dies?  Are you killing it via the script first or how does it die?  Is your job timing out due to long arsed call to the DB?  I've had DJ up for a year and it's not once quit or died yet.  So just wondering what you mean by `DJ dies`?

Comment: Good questions, yes the delayed_job process dies immediately when I off load some work to it. No timeouts are occurring. DJ is simply being asked to send a few emails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out `delayed_job` was executing a job causing a segmentation fault, which would kill the delayed_job daemon.

After debugging it turns out `Random.rand()` will cause a reproducible segmentation fault when run in a daemonized environment. This has to do with initial seeding and setup of the random generator, which apparently does not get handled properly by daemonize.

The solution: `Random.new.rand()`

Comment: Good to know. Glad it at least got fixed, but was a bugger to get, i bet. cheers.

Comment: We have provided a patch to the daemons gem, and it has been pulled in to the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if the weird behaviour in this [stack overflow DJ log question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195410/log-doesnt-work-in-production-with-delayed-job?rq=1) could account for the behaviour you had. The answer looks plausible too.  Stranger things have happened.

Pt 2:
[Permission issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279267/why-does-my-delayed-job-fail-without-rvm) could may very well be mucking it up too.  Is this in production or dev? Does it work in Dev?

PT 3: From the github page of DJm Make sure you are using MongoDB version 1.3 or newer. Are you?
pt 4: and this? `script/rails runner 'Delayed::Backend::Mongoid::Job.create_indexes'`

Lastly, as of today DJM is running red on Travis, with some errors that may effect you. I had a shoddy build in a gem once, driving me to drink only to be fixed 2 days later. http://travis-ci.org/#!/collectiveidea/delayed_job_mongoid/jobs/1962498

If that isn't it, throw on pry in the Gemfile, add `binding.pry` to that script starting at the top and working down.

Comment: this is in development. we have not yet released this app to production.

Comment: Yes, we're using MongoDB 2.0.6

Comment: Yes we have also created the indexes

Comment: Tried many versions (older and newest) of `delayed_job`,  `delayed_job_mongoid` and `mongoid` to no avail.